# How do I add more objects to the program?

Tags: java

I have started taking Java classes so I am fairly new and I got a task with "Bouncing balls". I have to make so that user could input how many balls he/she wants to see in the screen. I have tried doing for loops but I am completely sure I have done something wrong because I keep seeing one ball. Could anyone give me some pointers/hints/ or indicate the problem? Thank you :)

Program:

```
public class BouncingBall { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        // set the scale of the coordinate system
        StdDraw.setXscale(-1.0, 1.0);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-1.0, 1.0);

         // initial values
            double rx = Math.random();
            double ry = Math.random();    // position
            double vx = 0.015, vy = 0.023;     // velocity
            double radius = 0.05; // radius

        // main animation loop
        while (true)  { 

            // bounce off wall according to law of elastic collision
          //  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(rx + vx) > 1.0 - radius) vx = -vx;
            if (Math.abs(ry + vy) > 1.0 - radius) vy = -vy;

            // update position
         //   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            rx = rx + vx; 
            ry = ry + vy; 

            // clear the background
            StdDraw.clear(StdDraw.GRAY);

            // draw ball on the screen
          //  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK); 
            StdDraw.filledCircle(rx, ry, radius); 

            // display and pause for 20 ms
          //  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            StdDraw.show(20); 
        } 
    }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want `N` to be the number of balls here. Your problem is that the loop in line 3 is spanning the entire program, including the animation loop. So, instead of spawning N balls, you're running your game N-times each after the other.

Comment: Well, I kind of thought that repeating program would result in more balls appearing...

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. Think about it, if you want to play football with two balls, you throw another ball into the game instead of playing two 90-minute games after another.

Comment: Is it possible to do just with for? Or do I need any other statement? I tried to move for around and see what it does in different situation but I have not achieved more than slowing down the ball :(

Comment: Think about what you want to do. You want there to be two balls. How does your current system work? You save a position and velocity for your one ball and update it. It follows that to represent two balls, you will need two sets of position and velocity variables. However, since you want to have arbitrary numbers of balls (and because it is good practice), you should create a class `Ball` that holds those attributes. You can then have an array of balls, each of which is updated in every frame.

Comment: Oh i see. I will try that. Thank you very much. We have not yet covered much info about classes, their creations but I'll try to use google :) Again, thank you for answering